# Spark: Silently execute sc.wholeTextFiles

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I am loading about 200k text files in Spark using `input = sc.wholeTextFiles(hdfs://path/*)`
I then run a `println(input.count)`
It turns out that my spark shell outputs a ton of text (which are the path of every file) and after a while it just hangs without returning my result.

I believe this may be due to the amount of text outputted by `wholeTextFiles`. Do you know of any way to run this command silently? or is there a better workaround?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How large are your files?
From the `wholeTextFiles` [API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkContext):

> Small files are preferred, large files are also allowable, but may
>   cause bad performance.

In `conf/log4j.properties`, you can suppress excessive logging, like this:

```
# Set everything to be logged to the console
log4j.rootCategory=ERROR, console
```

That way, you'll get back only `res` to the *repl*, just like in the Scala (the language) *repl*.

Here are all other logging levels you can play with: [log4j API](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Level.html).

Comment: they are usually less than 1MB. Some can be very small (few kbs). The idea is to load them all and then create a graph using graphx. I don't see any other way of doing it than using wholeTextFiles

Comment: It's probably a good idea to now edit your question to include the  code and a sample file contents. I'm assuming that tuning down logging did not solve your problem?

Comment: I'll be experimenting on Monday and letting you know :)